# Want to echo a php variable from another page

Tags: php, include, echo

I want to echo a variable on a page which I've included form a different page. This to save space and separate php code from text data as much as possible.

In the page from where I fetch the variables (let's call it "aa.php") I have:

```
if ($whatever=="A") echo "somethingA";
if ($whatever=="B") echo "somethingB";
if ($whatever=="C") echo "somethingC";
```

I include it on the page where I want the data to show (let's call it "data.php"):

```
include 'aa.php';
$whatever = "B";
```

I want "B" to show on data.php, but it isn't echoing on the page at all (I'm guessing because it's actually on the other page?) -- How do I echo it on the page where I want the data to show, with as little clutter as possible?

Comment: Also, I'd use `require` instead of `include`. `include` is usually just not what you want :)

Comment: Yea, the only time you'd want to use include is if you are conditionally including files (i.e. if something include File A else include File B), or if you don't want a fatal error if the file isn't found (rare).

Also, you should click the check mark next to minitech's answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order seems to be the problem:

```
$whatever = "B";
include 'aa.php';
```