# echoing a message /error on a page from a different location/file

Tags: php, html

Ok, I have a script called profile.php and I would like the user  to interact with profile.php "form input" from a different html page or php script such as user_settings.php.

I would like to have the errors ONLY from profile.php to be displayed/echoed/printed on user_settings.php page. I have tried the following

----profile.php---

```
 <?php ob_start(); require_once ("core/init.php"); ?>
 <?php require ("includes/overall/header.php"); ?>

 <?php 
      if(has_access($session_user_id, 1) === true){
            $message[] = '<p class="admin">  **Admin**</p>';
      }
 ?>

   <div  id="mainInfo">
   <p class="profile"> Hello <?php echo $user_data['first_name'], '!' .output_message($message)  ;?> </p><br /><br />
  <?php

        if(isset($_FILES['image']) === true)
        {
            if(empty($_FILES['image']['name']) === true)
            {
                $errors_image[] = 'Please choose a file';
            }
            else
            {
                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');  

                $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

                if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true)
                {
                    change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);

                    header('Location: profile');
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    $errors_image[] = 'Incorrect file type. Allow: ';
                    echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                }
            }
        }
        if(empty($user_data['image']) === false)
        {
           echo '<p class="photo"><image src="', $user_data['image'],'" alt="', $user_data['first_name'], '\'s Profile Image"></p> <br>';
        }
    ?>



    <p class="usr_sttngs"> <a href="usr_sttngs">Update Info!</a></p><br />


    </div>  
    <?php require ("includes/overall/footer.php"); ?>
```

--------usr_sttngs.php------------

```
   <?php ob_start(); 

  require_once ("core/init.php");
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
  protect_page(); ?>

   <?php 

if(empty($_POST) === false)
{
    $required_fields = array('current_passwd','passwd', 'passwd_again');
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true)
        {
            $errors[] = '<p class="postad_msg">Fields marked with * are required.</p>';
            break 1;
        }
    }


    if (sha1($_POST['current_passwd']) === $user_data['passwd'])
    {
        if(trim($_POST['passwd']) !== trim($_POST['passwd_again']))
        {
            $errors[] = '<p class="postad_msg">New passwords DO NOT match!</p>';
        }
        else if (strlen($_POST['passwd']) < 6)
        {
            $errors[] = '<p class="postad_msg">New passwords must be at least 6 characters.</p>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = '<p class="postad_msg">Your current password is incorrect!</p>';
    }   
}
?>

  <?php require ("includes/overall/header.php"); ?>

    <div id="mainInfo">

                    <br /> <br /><p3>Change Password!</p3> <br /> <br />
                <?php 

                    if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success']))
                    {
                        $message[] = '<p class="postad_msg">Your password has been changed successfully.</p>';
                    }

                        if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true)
                        {      
                            change_passwd($session_user_id, $_POST['passwd'] );
                            //redirect
                            header('Location: usr_sttngs?success');                                         
                            //exit
                            exit();                                                 
                        }
                        else if(empty($errors) === false)
                        {
                            output_errors($errors); 
                        }
                ?>     

        <form method="post" action="usr_sttngs">
            <fieldset>              
                <label for="currentpasswd">Current password* </label>
                <input placeholder="Type your current password" type="password" name="current_passwd" size="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo htmlentities($current_passwd); ?>" /><br /><br />
                <label for="last_name">New Password* </label>
                <input placeholder="New Password" type="password" name="passwd" size="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo htmlentities($new_passwd); ?>" /><br /><br />
                <label for="email">New Password Again* </label>
                <input placeholder="Retype New Password"  type="password" name="passwd_again" size="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo htmlentities($new_passwd_again); ?>" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="center">
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password" />
                 <?php echo output_errors($errors); ?>
                 <?php echo output_message($message);?>

            </fieldset>





        </form>

    <p4>Change profile photo!</p4> <br /> <br />

    <form action="profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset class="center">
            <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit">

            <?php echo output_errors($errors_image); 
                  require_once ('$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]\profile.php');
            ?>

        </fieldset>          
    </form>



  <br /><br /><br /><p4>Upload your resume!</p4> <br /> 

    <form action="profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset class="center">
            <input type="file" name="resume"> <input type="submit">
        </fieldset>          
  </form>

 </div>

 <?php require ("includes/overall/footer.php"); ?>
```

I tried something I read on the following post [Want to echo a php variable from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831493/want-to-echo-a-php-variable-from-another-page) but I did not get the desired results.  So I tried to include the required_once 'profile.php' ; at the very top of the user_setting.php file and that just gives me a blank page.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You say you get a blank page, this might be caused by PHP errors and your server might be configured to not show them. Put these two lines at the top of your files and post if there are any changes: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` (got them from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083533/how-to-have-php-display-errors-ive-added-ini-set-and-error-reporting-but-jus))

Comment: Hi user1781026  here is the error I get   -------Warning: require_once(profile): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\dir\subdir\user_settings.php on line 97 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'profile' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\dir\subdir\usr_sttngs.php on line 97----

Comment: Try this: `require_once('profile.php')`. Make sure both profile.php and user_setting.php are in the same directory, if not use something like `require_once('directory/profile.php')`

Comment: They are both in the root directory and I even tried the following   require_one('$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/profile.php'); to no avail :(

Comment: That may be caused by a few things: You wrote `_one` instead of `_once`, and variables don't work like that in single quotes `'like this'`. You must also put DOCUMENT_ROOT in quotes. Corrected: `require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'profile.php');`

Comment: _one instead of _once was a typO on this page bc I wouldve gotten an error pertaining to that.  I corrected the DOCUMENT_ROOT to "DOCUMENT_ROOT" but same thing but same thing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require or Require_once must be called before any HTML is displayed.

Try placing your require_once at the beginning of the file.

**EDITED**

Try the following test code to see if you can get it working.

**The profile.php should contain the following:**

```
<?php

echo "profile.php is displaying correctly";

?>
```

**The user_settings.php should contain the following:**

```
<?php

require_once("profile.php");

?>
```

See if you can get this basic code to work. Post your results

**I get the bellow page when I try the code above:**

[image]

Comment: I get a blank page :(

Comment: I tried both ways; at the beginning of the file and before any html code and I yield the same result - blank page!!

Comment: I'd imagine that there is an error with profile.php. Either there is an issue locating the file or there is some type of syntax error in there. Try enabling error reporting.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and "profile.php is displaying correctly" shows on both pages. I would hope that this simple code would work :).  but hey I'm just beginning to learn so I can make simple mistakes easily

Comment: That's a good thing. That lets me know that your profile.php and user_settings.php are in the same directory. The only culprit at this point has to be some type of syntax issue in profile.php. Can you post  the full code for both pages?

Comment: Also try adding ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning of your first php file so that you can see if any errors are being reported.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46104/discussion-between-j03z-and-user3001162)